# Shellscript - Check Running services

Tags: bash, awk

I'm new in Shellscript, and i'm getting some problems. I need a script to check if the services are running or not, if its not running, and dont exist the flag, start all services. What i'm doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash

file= "$PIN_HOME/apps/DE_BILL_MI_BRM/alarmistica/flags/intervencao.flag"

# Check if services are running 
for service in $BRM_SERVICES
do
    if  [ps -ef | grep $service | grep -v grep | awk 'NR>1{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i==1) print "Services not running", i}' ]; then
        echo $service " is not running correctly"
    else
        if [ -f "$file" ]; then
          echo "Flag exists. The service will not start"
        else
          echo "$file not found. Starting all services"
          pin_ctl start all
        fi      
    fi  
done
```

When `($i==1)`, the services is not running!

But the results is not corresponding. For exemple, when the services are down, the script dont start the services...

Comment: What is `$i`?  Also, do you define `$BRM_SERVICES`?  Not in this code.

Comment: Why did you not use `pidof $service` or `ps -C $service` ?

Comment: At the very least, you have two spacing errors: `file="$PIN..." and `if [ ps -ef ...` are required.

Answer (score 0):

For checking process tables, use `pgrep` instead.

```
#!/bin/bash

file= "$PIN_HOME/apps/DE_BILL_MI_BRM/alarmistica/flags/intervencao.flag"

# Check if services are running 
for service in $BRM_SERVICES
do
   pgrep -f "$service";
   exstat=$?; # This checks the exit status
   if [ "$exstat" -eq 0 ] && ! [ -f "$file" ]; then
      echo "pgrep returned exit status $extstat";
   else
      echo "$file not found. Starting all services"
      pin_ctl start all
    fi       
done
```

Comment: $BRM_SERVICES is a variable, contains all the services :)

Comment: Not sure I understand... what is the variable output when you do `echo $BRM_SERVICE`